# DOM envy. (I am using hidden inputs to store data, but there is so much data the page is slow)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am passing 3 HashMaps that contain data pertaining to 13 different time periods, to a jsp page.

The data from these maps is used to populate and alter a summary data div (that consists of the summed total of the different datasets, **for the selected ranges**, so it could 1 of 13, 2 of 13, all 13 and so on.  However the 3 datasets are large.  In total there are 910 = (13*7)+(13*7)+(13*8*7) individual values.

Following me so far ?

The selected data is used by javascript/jquery when a check bx is selected - so there are 13 checkbox and when checked the data is included in total, when unchecked the data is subtracted. The selected subset of data is used to plot a graph with flot. I am not using an HTML form.

Currently I am using hidden inputs *behind* a visible checkbox - this has slowed everything right down, because the DOM is so large ? What are better options that will increase the responsiveness (specifically a jquery dialog that contains all the data).

My ideas so far : 
  Passing the data in as a json string ?
  Using input tag attributes rather than 910 individual inputs ?

Thanks!
(any solution must be compatible with ie6 and ie8)

Comment: How are you accessing the hidden fields - what is the jQuery selector used?

Comment: At the moment I am using a multiple class selector. Each hidden input gets two class names, I then select base don them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to attach the relevent values for a given checkbox to it. This is like storing it in attributes expect for you're not creating expando property issues. As far as storing the full data sets id stick with jsut the hashes as a global variable, or you could attach them to the `form` element the checkboxes belong to with `.data()` as well (assuming the are actually in a  `form`).

So for example we might see something like:

```
$('#dataForm').data(
  'hashOne', 
   hashOne
).data(
  'hashTwo', 
  hashTwo
).data(
  'hashThree', 
  hashThree
);

$('#dataForm #checkboxOne').change(function(){
  var form = $(this).parents('form');
  if($(this).is(':checked'){
     $(this).data('currentValue', form.data('hashOne').someValueKey);
  }
});
```

Comment: How would I get the data (its a request attribute from a servlet) into the jquery ready script ? At the moment I am using jstl to loop through the data and create hidden inputs.  this is the essence of the problem, I don't need or want to create hidden inputs but how do I get the data into javascript/jquery without using them ?

Comment: Use an ajax call which returns a json object with all the values

Comment: I was trying to avoid any more requests (http or xmlhttp).

Comment: Then include the json in a script block when you render the page

Comment: "include the json in a script block" huh ? I am probably being dumb - how can I get the data, which is a map as a request attribute into a json object on page render ?

Comment: Instead of iterating over the map and using the data to create `input` elements just write it out as a string. I dont know java but i would think this is the easy part. in fact in php i would just use `json_encode($myHash)` and that would give me a properly escaped and encoded JSON string with all the native php values converted to their js counterparts that i could print into a script tag in my view. Isn't there some kind of transformer/formatter class you can throw a hash/value object/array at that does essentially the same thing?